# setRecordingHint with Camera2

Tags: android, android-camera2

What is the [Camera2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) equivalent of [setRecordingHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRecordingHint(boolean))?

Answer (score 0):

Use the request template [TEMPLATE_RECORD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html#TEMPLATE_RECORD).

Comment: Besides the (brief) docs for TEMPLATE_RECORD, I don't think there's any other documentation that discusses this.  

I know it's the right solution since I wrote the implementation of setRecordingHint for LIMITED hardware level or better camera devices; it maps to TEMPLATE_RECORD.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the same as previewRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT_VIDEO_RECORD);

e.g.

```
     CaptureRequest.Builder previewRequest = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
     previewRequest.addTarget(previewSurface);
     previewRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_CAPTURE_INTENT_VIDEO_RECORD);
     session.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequest.build(), null, null);
```